# source install + opencv source install

Tags: ros, opencv, rviz, source, fedora

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm installing ROS Indigo from source on Fedora 23 and I also have a source install of openCV 2.4.12.

After I compiled everything when I try to run `rosrun rviz rviz`

I have this error :

```
rosrun rviz rviz
/home/malcolm/ros_catkin_ws/source_indigo/install_isolated/lib/rviz/rviz: error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_videostab.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But it is installed :

```
$ pwd
/usr/local/lib

$ ls -la | grep libopencv_videostab
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root      26 Jun 20 12:53 libopencv_videostab.so -> libopencv_videostab.so.2.4
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root      29 Jun 20 12:53 libopencv_videostab.so.2.4 -> libopencv_videostab.so.2.4.12
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root  297416 Jun 28 12:06 libopencv_videostab.so.2.4.12
```

I found this [very similar question](http://answers.ros.org/question/217769/corrupted-ros-install-on-debian-jessie-after-update/) but I already reinstalled opencv and reinstalled ros and it didn't change anything. It worked before with the repo install.

Any idea on what is happening ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238266/source-install-+-opencv-source-install/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2016-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I don't understand why exactly but this seems to be the answer :

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "/usr/local/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf'
$ sudo ldconfig
```

Found the solution from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040746/cant-open-video-using-opencv)

---

Originally posted by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) with karma: 1172 on 2016-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BrannonKing](https://answers.ros.org/users/27276/brannonking/) on 2016-06-30**:
Yes, this is something to understand when compiling on Fedora. Unless you manually specify a lib prefix when calling `configure/cmake`, the result will go to `/usr/local/lib` or `/usr/local/lib64`. You need to add both of those the lib search path using `ldconfig`, i.e. `sudo ldconfig path1 path2`